# Ternary operator in Java 8, compilation with Maven

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception, compiler-errors, primitive-types

Consider this class:

```
package be.duo.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + method());
        }
    }

    private int method() {
        return (Math.random() > 0.5d) ? 1 : null;
    }

}
```

The method() has return type `int`, which is a primitive type.

Consider the ternary operator used in the return statement:

- it compiles with the Java 8 default compiler, but this will result in a NullPointerException at runtime, why?
- using Maven this will result in a compile time error

```
[ERROR] error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
[ERROR] <null> cannot be converted to int
```

Can somebody explain to me **why** it behaves different?

Comment: compilation done with Maven

Comment: It compiles fine for me with javac 1.8.0_45

Comment: I get a NullPointerException with Java 1.8.0_31 which is to be expected (I assume getIntValue() is being called in Integer.toString()).

Comment: It's behavior depends on `Math.random()` output, not on java version. Based on random number, either you get 1 or NPE as output.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's not to do with the `println`, it's just because `method()` has return type `int`.

Comment: It's not a "short if" notation. It's the ternary operator, which is not a replacement for if.

Comment: @Kayaman Technically it's not called the ternary operator either. It's called the conditional operator.

Comment: Regardless whether such code behaves differently in different Java versions (either at compile or at run time), I never would let such code slip into the code base. Why on earth should an `int` typed method ever return `null`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp: The ternary operator will box each operand of it to an `Integer` which can contain an `int` and `null`. When the method then returns this `Integer` object, it will use the `toString()` method of it when printing to the console. Here it will fail because of the `toString()` implementation of  `Integer` with a `null` value. At least that's how I believe it will execute without looking at source code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The method doesn't return an `Integer` object. Look at the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it should be legal under Java 8.

See [Table 15.25-E. Conditional expression type (Reference 3rd operand, Part III)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

```
3rd → null
2nd ↓        
int   lub(Integer,null)
```

`lub(Integer,null)` should be `Integer`. Basically if you have a conditional of the form `boolean ? int : null`, the result of the expression should be `Integer` and it gets unboxed. (I think you already know this is what happens.)

So according to the specification it should be the same.

Seems like a compiler bug. There have been quite a few of these found, I would say try updating to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which Java 8 minor version you use, but i can compile under java 1.8.

```
C:\Users\XXXX>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_31

C:\Users\XXXX>javac Main.java

C:\Users\XXXX>java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Main.method(Main.java:15)
        at Main.execute(Main.java:10)
        at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```